# Android Studio project running error

Tags: android

When i try to run my project in Android Studio. it always give me this error. i have try to clear and rebuild, but it's still not working....

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Z:\Android\CalculatorAutumn7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\5\slice_1\classes.dex (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: show your **`build.Gradle`**

Answer (score 0):

## you must Provide right file path

**Read File From Assets**

- use tyr catch block
- give file_name + extension (like .txt)

```
      BufferedReader mRreader = null;
        try {
            mRreader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("your_file_name.txt");
           // do reading,usually loop until end of file reading 

           String mLine; 

            while ((mLine = mRreader.readLine()) != null) { //process line
            /// write code
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception 
        } finally {
            if (mRreader != null) {
                try {
                    mRreader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) { //log the exception } } }


                }

            }
```